# *Org Src file.org[ R ]*: C-c ' is undefined

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'm trying to edit a code snippet in org-mode. When I type `C-c '` in org mode buffer, it opens up the editor window in R-mode, but it doesn't know about C-c ' and cannot be killed by `C-x k` since when I execute that command I get a message in the message buffer:

> Wrong type argument: overlayp, nil

Is there a way to force kill a buffer? Right now I'm restarting Emacs. Is there a faster way? Why is this doing in the first place?

The elisp debugger gives:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument overlayp nil)
  delete-overlay(nil)
  #[nil "\301!\207" [org-edit-src-overlay delete-overlay] 2]()
  kill-buffer("*Org Src notes.org<lec>[ R ]*")
  call-interactively(kill-buffer nil nil)
  command-execute(kill-buffer)
```

If I try to use `org-edit-src-exit` I get:

> org-edit-src-exit: This is not a sub-editing buffer, something is wrong

Comment: This looks like R mode defines a hook that messes something up in the way it is started by Org. Wrt killing the buffer: Org adds a hook to `kill-buffer-hook` when you edit source code. To remove it: `M-: (setq kill-buffer-hook nil)` (while in the buffer with the source) then you can kill the buffer as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Did you, by any chance, change the mode of the buffer you opened with `C-c '`? That's Emacs bug #19887: [discussion](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2015-02/msg00617.html), and is supposed to have been fixed in February 2015.

If you run into this problem again and are stuck with the editing buffer that doesn't want to close, @wvxvw's suggestion will let you close it.